# Science fiction novel about a group of genetically engineered young adults that lived in a "pod" or family group

Tags: story-identification, novel, genetic-engineering

I'm looking for the name of a science fiction novel from the late 90's or early 2000's.

The plot revolved around a group of genetically engineered young adults that lived in a "pod" or family group. They were potentially telepathic or communicated using pheromones. If I remember correctly, they were chasing someone, a male who fled down to Earth. People still lived on Earth, but were not advanced like the collectivist group in the "pod". I believe they lived on a ring orbiting the Earth?

Answer (score 5):

[Singularity's Ring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity%27s_Ring) by Paul Melko

> The story is set in a future after a singularity event, which caused
> the bulk of humanity to disappear. The focus of this event was a huge
> space station which rings the Earth, and which remains uninhabited
> after the singularity.

---

> **The majority of humans are now genetically engineered to form pods,
> groups of 2 to 5 individuals with the ability to form an emergent
> personality from those individuals.**
>
> The story follows a young pod named Apollo Papadopulos who is training
> to become the captain of a new starship which is to be launched soon.
> Apollo Papadopulos is composed of five teenagers; Strom, Meda, Quant,
> Manuel and Moira. The story moves between the points of view of each
> of these individuals, and that of Apollo Papadopulos itself.